# Fail of Vectors Comparison

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I'm trying to compare two vectors , and as what I know vectors support the relational operators and it works in this way: compare the 1st element in v1 with 1st element in v2 and so on ..

why the result of the following code is (true) where the last element in v1 > v2 ?!

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <vector>
using namespace std;

void main()
{

    vector <int> V1 = { 2,1,0,3 };
    vector <int> V2 = { 3,4,2,2 };

    cout << (V1 <= V2);  //print true !!


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: same reason that "cbad" < "decc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=` compare the contents of both vectors lexicographicall.
From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare :

> Lexicographical comparison is a operation with the following properties:
>
> - Two ranges are compared element by element.
> - The **first mismatching element defines** which range is lexicographically less or greater than the other.

This is why a string "abc**d**x" is less than "abc**e**d" and [**2**,1,0,3] is less than [**3**,4,2,2].

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` is a data container and has nothing to do with the mathematical concecpt of a vector beside containing more than one element.

The [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operators/) of `std::vector` states how the comparison works:

> The equality
>   comparison (operator==) is performed by first comparing sizes, and if
>   they match, the elements are compared sequentially using operator==,
>   stopping at the first mismatch (as if using algorithm equal).
>
> The less-than comparison (operator<) behaves as if using algorithm
>   lexicographical_compare, which compares the elements sequentially
>   using operator< in a reciprocal manner (i.e., checking both a